# PCI SATA controller recommendation

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sata, pci

I want to add a couple of SATA drives using a PCI SATA controller. Do you have any recommendations for me that will work with 12.04?

Comment: Can you use PCI-Express 2.0 x1?

Comment: No PCI express please.

Answer (score 1):

First let start by saying that SATA PCI cards are hard to come by.  But take a look at this card [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816102065).

It states that it has Red Hat Linux, SuSE Linux, Linux open source code.  I can not find out if it has been tested with 12.04, but this site [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=815&num=1) has tested the cart with 7.04.

I know this may not be the answer that you are looking for, but I could not find any other information or cards :).

I asked some of the guys that I work with, and I was told that if the card works with 7.04, that it should work with 12.04. but there is no way for me to verify that, I hope that you understand